# Drupal Multisite, MAMP and SVN Best Practices?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I successfully set-up Drupal Multisites with:

- site1.domain.com
- site2.domain.com
- site3.domain.com

using Virtualhosts and editing the etc/hosts with MAMP on my localhost. I then deployed it using SVN (it deploys automatically) on the live site.

**The Problem:** when I type "Site1.domain.com" because it goes to my localhost instead of my live site. Is there anyway to avoid this? (apart from renaming the subdomain, because it speeds up deployment)

Answer (score 1):

Just check your virtual host settings in httpd.conf file, are you using IP address to redirect them?

And if its directing to your localhost, just check your `host` file, if might be redirecting because of that

Comment: Yes it is because of my host file. It is redirecting to my localhost. However, I need that because I have to develop on my localhost. The problem is that even after I deploy, when I try to access my live site, I can't. It still redirects to my localhost. Is there a easy way to switch this ON/OFF?

Comment: @JK Thng if you try to access from some other computer, then too does it redirects to your localhost?

Comment: No it doesn't. Its only on my local computer.